# Disable a custom button from directive

Tags: angular

I have a custom button like:

```
<my-button [permission]="'NONE'" [disabled]="!projectForm.valid" type="submit">
   Save
</my-button>
```

If the permissions are 'NONE' I have to disable a button. Therefore I am doing this in directive:

**permission.directive.ts**

```
@Input() public readonly permission: string;

constructor(
    private readonly element: ElementRef,
    private readonly ref: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}

public ngOnInit() {
    if (this.permission === 'NONE') {
       this.element.nativeElement.disabled = true;
   }
}
```

How ever, it doesn't disable the button. I tried changing the button color and that works perfectly:

```
this.element.nativeElement.style.color = 'blue';
```

Since the color changing worked, I thought I might need to trigger the Change Detection:

```
this.element.nativeElement.disabled = true;
this.element.nativeElement.style.color = 'blue';
```

The result is still the same, color is changed but the button is not disabled.

Since **my-button** is a wrapper of **button**, I tried disabling the button element itself, but the result was the same (Not disabled).

```
this.element.nativeElement.children[0].disabled = true;
```

After that I thought since the style.color worked, setting it's style.display to 'none' could also work. Unfortunately that didn't work out either. Does anyone have a clue why changing it's color works perfectly, but changing the disabled or display state doesn't?

Comment: [permission]="'NONE'" is the same as just permission="NONE". Square brackets are used for interpolating members of the component.

Comment: I've noticed you have included ChangeDetectorRef but not used it, have you tried ref.detectChanges()?

Comment: @Max Sorry, I forgot to put it here. Yes I used ref.detectChanges(). And regarding square brackets, I am aware of it. I adapted the code for this question and just encapsulated the string with ''.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the ElementRef (use with care as Angular official documentation states [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) because of XSS attacks) or any custom directive you can make use of CSS class to achieve the same behavior.

The following CSS class may apply to buttons and you can create custom ones for different elements.

```
.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   user-select: none;
   color: grey;
   cursor: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
<my-button [disabled]="!projectForm.valid || permission === 'NONE'" type="submit">
   Save
</my-button>
```

Comment: It has to be handled by directive as there is a logic happening on determining permission

Comment: How about: `[disabled]="isButtonDisabled(projectForm.valid, 'NONE')"` Where you can then define a function in the component that returns true or false. It seems that although you are changing the disabled attribute in js, Angular is reading the projectForm.valid value and changing it back immediately everytime the lifecycle is complete.

Answer (score 0):

@Dino, use a getter to set Disabled element.nativeElement

```
@Input()
set disabled(value)
{
     this.element.nativeElement.disabled = value; 
}
<my-button [disabled]="!projectForm.valid || permission === 'NONE'" ..>

//or
@Input()
set disabled(value)
{
     this.element.nativeElement.disabled = value || this.permision=='NONE'; 
}
<my-button [permission]="'NONE'" [disabled]="!projectForm.valid"...>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use ngAfterViewChecked().

```
export class TutorialDirective implements AfterViewChecked {
disable = true;

constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
  this.el.nativeElement.disabled = true;
  }
}
```